# Reading text into a richtextbox

Tags: c#, file, richtextbox

I have a problem, i wanna read out a Text file into a `richTextBox`, i use this method, to load it into the `TextBox`:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\users\TextFile1.txt", Encoding.Default);
    }
```

The problem is, that it just shows me the text if i press a letter on the Keyboard, like "a" or "b". I searched for it in google, but i couldn't find something similar.
I hope that someone can help me here ;) 
btw: using Visual Studio Express 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use the textChanged event to display your text file , try to put the same code into your form load or any other event you want

Comment: Exactly, this event should fire when the user types something into the richTextBox. It seems like that's what's happening.

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfectly :) But why isnt it working there?